# Why printing arguments in python doesn't work?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to explain to my friend, how sys.argv works. And I ran this snippet from command line (tested on cmd and bash).

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" bla stas
```

But to my surprise this is the output:

```
['-c', 'bla', 'stas']
```

And I'm stumped - why the expression in quotes `"import sys; print(sys.argv)"` is not part of the argument list? Shouldn't it be at the second place like this:

```
['-c', '"import sys; print(sys.argv)"', 'bla', 'stas']
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

> `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the `-c` command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to the string `'-c'`.

Putting the command itself in `argv[]` as well would be wrong, since it's not an argument to the script. The arguments are just `bla` and `stas`.

Answer (score 0):

Python treats the `-c` argument as a special case and doesn't put the code string into `sys.argv`.